# Water entering a slab house

Tags: water, hardwood-floor, slab

I live in a slab home that has a partial brick front in central NC. After a particularly bad bout of rain (hurricane), I discovered about a week later that some of the engineered hardwood floor in the foyer had what looks like water damage.

What should I look for in terms of potential avenues of water getting into the house? Could it be from the brick facing? Cracks in the slab?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the surface level of the soil around your foyer.  We homeowners tend to mulch planting beds around the house which composts and turns to soil, next year we add more.  After a few years this brings the soil up to a level that is over the level of the slab which can lead to water infiltrating the house.

Comment: The previous owner had several inches of mulch...I had removed that mulch. However, the soil looks like it is several inches below the slab. It is possible the water went above this during the storm...I should of went outside and looked!

Answer (score 1):

First determine if it is water coming in through the "weep" holes, or it is a roof leak running down the inside of the wall. If there is a plumbing vent in this outside wall, then that could be the source of a leak.

If you determine that surface drainage is allowing water in through the weep holes, then you should regrade around the house to establish swales which drain water away from the house.

I live in a neighborhood of 50-year-old tract houses on 10,000 sq ft lots in which the original swales have pretty much filled in. Our streets run E-W and the ground slopes down to the W from a N-S ridge on the E to a creek on the W. I personally know of 3 houses which have had water ingress in recent heavy rains.

Our lot (87' wide) has an elevation change of 2.5' down from E to W. When we bought our house in 1978 the swale on the E side (our house faces N) was 90% filled in. I used a tiller to loosen the soil and reestablished the swale. It needs it again. This time I will use a mattock, a shovel and a wheelbarrow to transfer soil to the W side of our lot. We have a sunken living room, but it is on the W side (downhill).

A year ago a neighbor had water coming into her house on the E side due to the swale being filled in. Her house has a sunken living room on the E (uphill side of her S facing house); she asked my wife to have me take a look. In 6 to 9 hr of work with a mattock, shovel and wheelbarrow in 3 sessions I was able to redirect water away from the house, and that house has stayed dry in the year since, despite heavy rains. The swales need further deepening. I did this as proof of concept, and I may do more on that drainage. The clay soil is easily workable at the correct moisture content. If dry it is like concrete.

Some people in the neighborhood have had underground "French" drains professionally installed on the uphill side. Re-establishing surface drainage is much cheaper and I believe works better.

Answer (score 0):

I built berms with burried logs, wood chips (you can have the tree cutting services working your area dump them.in your yard for free *give them a nice tip though) yard debris, rocks. You burry the logs down below the frost line and you build up with branches and sticks interwoven then woodchips and garbage rock (crush run in likeness). You are going to want the wood chips to fill the gaps. Then you want to layer on dirt and  leaftyard waste pack this in wall on it being mindful of the branches and sticks as well as rocks. But get it compacted in nicely. Take the dirt you dug out and flop that on the top of this berm. It should be a decent mound sitting partially perpendicular at any point where the lions share of the water drains to. This berm then redirects the water flow over from where it is flowing. You can build corresponding berms that face this berm on the other side of the drainage flow. Or a chain of berms that ping pong the flow of the water playing into the desired route you.wish the water to go. You must compensate for where the water is to go by ensuring that between these berms is the low spot. So it also may require grading the area a little. It will require watching how large amounts of.water flow through your peoperty
Also you cant berm and swale into your neighbors yard or driveway, unless you are in the business of giving away five figures in cash.

My issue is i have negative slope and i sit on the end cap of 20 some houses with back to back yards that are much higher than my back yard. My neighbor who just sold his house to new neighbors. Laid down some sort of slick nearly impenetrable sheet in his back yard then dumped 1 1/2 inch cobblestones over this to his back yard. Some water from the street drains down the driveway and into this slip and slide with smooth rounded rocks that offer the absolute minimum in resistance. Then this water is off into my yard. Whats worse is that the house is in part around 8 to 10 feet from his proprty line. This neighbor also had a french drain installes by a real einstein who doesnt believe in physics. How do i know? Well the end of the french drain ends on an "upward sweep" to the road which is higher. So the water buckles right into my front yard where it has destroyed my driveway (which was already in its state when i moved in) this has sunk the driveway and the walkway to the front door and it literally floods the watermain the front yard and then down to the low point which disperses wide and flat making the front entire opposite side one massive shallow puddle.
I have trenched down to create a moat or a channel for when it rains but therw isnt anything outside of at least $20k that i can do for the sheer volume of water that comes down.

I researched drainage for 2 years. I found out that a good way to use this water is to use a tier system. So it first absorbs and then floods down to the next tier and so forth. It has worked brilliantly. It hasnt fully solved the issue but it definitely has helped curtail the severity. These tier are channeled down to the low point in a sweeping fashion to level with it..they dont drop grade or ripple the entire yard they just fade into the landscape. Meeting the lower level of ground on the lowest end. The lowest tier is the longest because thats the very last line of defense from the water it. An Eagle eye view they are tear drop shape with the broad side collecting and absorbing the water or passing it down the way to where it is desired. It wont go down to the next tier until it is completely saturated with all the water it will take on. Then it meanders down to the next level. This tear drop shape is followed by the next tier following the outline of the last one with adequate width down the length to compensate and hold the proper amount of water.

This is a wonderful technique for slowing water and getting adequate and good use of the water on your land. It would keep your soil moist longer and the water would travel from high to low much slower which will help keep nutrients and amendments in your soil. A pooling rushing on large swaths will quickly wash away precious nutrients. Where tiering will make it take the steps (if you follow me).

I had my width at about 3 and 1/2 feet (42 inches) the pools were about 2 feet wide and around 7 to 9 inches deep at the deepest point which will be positioned up against the front side of the step higher. This pool eventually becomes level on the down slope with everything else. You can have the pools meet further down the length then turn into one and then none. There is no wrong or right answer. It is a great way to use the water that meanders through your property if yoy have a slope. It saves you on having to water as much.
I worked from bottom to  top.

The tiers i used woodchips i got for free from a tree cutting service and i used heavy logs and rocks in the bottom which i dug into the slope at a depth of 7 inches. I tamped in the logs and large rocks. Then i used woodchips and the dirt i dug out to cover it all up. I would water heavily, the newly laid down material and i would walk and "stomp march" this down well compacting it. I used some dump truck crappy fill dirt thag i paid 60 dollars for as a tip (the builders needed to dump it somewhere and i was close by and i tipped them), bagged top soil and some dirt from another area of my property to finish it off at about 2 to 3 inches of dirt on the top of it once i was satisfied with the results. This soil you.want to compact while the wood chips are humid but not moist. If you did this right the woodchips will have a hot temp in the center, this is good because they will start breaking down and composting. This first layer of dirt will sink and seep down. It should. You should cover it with more soil as needed.you may tamp it down too if you would like. You wont need to do this more than 3 times. By then it can be sodded or seeded with grass seed. You should get some deep penetrating long root system grass. Wood chips are a curious thing that they absorb a significant amount of water and then release it at a trinkle. When they have had enough water they hold what they have and cast off what they dont. This js why this makes for a great tool for managing your water.

I must caution those who have a steep grade this could end badly for you as a steep hill with a quick dramatic change of grade will have the water at a strength that it cant contend with on such an angle. Though it can be done there are better materials than what i am suggesting. There is better ways to reinforce the hill and so on. This is what worked for me again it isnt perfect but it is the best use of materials i could get and using them to conserve a necessary element for my garden yard while not messing up my house. While i save the money for rare competent individuals who know what they are doing and can read the land and the unique details working together to create the problem. Then they know how to castrate the issue for at least several decades if not forever.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).